# Is that possible to write the below query using CTE recursion?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
create table #temp (date date)
declare @X date
set @X = '2016-7-01'
declare @Y date 
set @Y = cast (getdate() as date)
while(@X<=@Y) 
begin
if (datename(WEEKDAY,@X) = 'Sunday')
insert into #temp values (@X)
set @X = cast(((cast(@X as datetime))+1)as date)
continue
end
select * from #temp
drop table #temp
```

Is that possible to write the above query using CTE recursion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CTE to create a numbers table. You can then use the numbers table to get your dates like so:

```
Declare @Startdate Datetime = '2016-07-01'
Declare @EndDate Datetime = '2016-08-29'

;with
 N0 as (SELECT 1 as n UNION ALL SELECT 1)
,N1 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N0 t1, N0 t2)
,N2 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N1 t1, N1 t2)
,N3 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N2 t1, N2 t2)
,N4 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N3 t1, N3 t2)
,nums as (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as num FROM N4)
SELECT DATEADD(day,num-1,@startdate) as thedate
FROM nums
WHERE num <= DATEDIFF(day,@startdate,@enddate) + 1
and datename(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(day,num-1,@startdate)) = 'Sunday'
```

Each table (`N0` to `nums`) effectively multiplies the number of rows in the previous 'table', so you end up with 65,536 rows of numbers in `nums` (you can do less or more by adding or removing table `NX` as required). Then, use the numbers table to add days to your start date(`SELECT DATEADD(day,num-1,@startdate) as thedate`) , where the dates returned are in your date range, and the `weekday` is Sunday.

Also, because the numbers in `nums` start at 1, we use `nums-1` in our select, so as to avoid skipping over the first date in our series, effectively giving us `DATEADD(day, 0, @startdate)` in our first row.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like explained here: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/12/29/sql-server-get-date-of-all-weekdays-or-weekends-of-the-year/

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECALRE @EndDate DATETIME

SET @StartDate = '2016-07-01'
SET @EndDate = GETDATE()

;WITH cte AS (

    SELECT 
        1 AS DayID,
        @StartDate AS FromDate,
        DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) AS Dayname

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        cte.DayID + 1 AS DayID,
        DATEADD(d, 1, cte.FromDate),
        DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d, 1, cte.FromDate)) AS Dayname
    FROM cte
    WHERE DATEADD(d, 1, cte.FromDate) < @EndDate
)
SELECT FromDate AS Date, Dayname
FROM cte
WHERE Dayname IN ('Sunday')
```

I'm thinking there's be a more efficient way to do this by using a numbers table and a factor of 7 (depending on how many dates you need to get, possible pre-calc the first sunday from your start date, then join all numbers that are factors of 7 from a numbers table), but the above works well enough also.

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte
as
(
select getdate() as datee
union all
select dateadd(day,1,datee)
from cte
where datediff(day,getdate(),datee)<100
)
select * from cte
where datename(WEEKDAY,datee) = 'Sunday'
```

You will hit max recursion limit as well ,to avoid..that use something like below..

```
option ( MaxRecursion 0 )
```

I would solve this using numbers table if i am not constrained by the need to use recursive cte   ,which is  also way faster than Recursive cte..

```
select 
dateadd(day,n,getdate()) as datee 
from numbers
where n<100 and datename(weekday,dateadd(day,n,getdate()))='sunday'
```

To learn why you need numbers table,check this link..https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable